# Change columnCount depending on browser width (responsive)

Tags: layout, column, phtml

I'm currently using the below code (in **list.phtml**) to show 4 columns on my homepage for my products.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>

<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="note-msg-empty-catalog">
        <h3><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></h3>
        <?php echo $this->__('This is a custom CMS block displayed if category is empty.') ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('You can replace it with any custom content.') ?>

    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="list-left">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                        <div class="desc std">
                            <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-right">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist tooltips"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare tooltips"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
            <div class="label-product">             
                <?php if($_product->getData('new')){echo '<span class="new">'.$this->__('New').'</span>';  }?>
                <?php if($_product->getData('sale')){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
            </div>

        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
     <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $pageLayout=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate(); ?>
    <?php if ($pageLayout="page/1column.phtml"):?>
        <?php $_columnCount = 4 ?>
    <?php else: ?>  
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid row">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <div class="wrapper-hover">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(228); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <div class="product-shop">
                        <div class="price-box-border"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?></div>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                       <div class="desc_grid"><?php $small_getDescription = strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription());
                             if (strlen($small_getDescription) < 70) echo($small_getDescription);
                             else { echo mb_substr($small_getDescription, 0, 70,'UTF-8').'...';} ?></div>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Details') ?>" class="button btn-details" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></span></span></button>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" rel="tooltip" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a  title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?> " href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" rel="tooltip" class="link-compare "><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
                    <div class="label-product">             
                        <?php if($_product->getData('new')){echo '<span class="new">'.$this->__('New').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('sale')){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

More specifically in the code above is this part:

```
 <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $pageLayout=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate(); ?>
    <?php if ($pageLayout="page/1column.phtml"):?>
        <?php $_columnCount = 4 ?>
    <?php else: ?>  
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Since my website is responsive, when it gets to smaller screens, the 4 columns are extremely narrow. How can I make it so that when it reaches a certain max-width that it changes from 4 columns to 2?

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to be using a Bootstrap (or similar) grid, you should be able to achieve desired effect by removing row wrappers and adding a col-md-* class to the li.

In the "Grid mode" section of your list.phtml replace

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid row">
    <?php endif ?>
```

with

```
<ul class="products-grid row">
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

and

```
<?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
</ul>
<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

with

```
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Then add the col-md-* class do the li element. For two columns it would look like that:

```
<li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-3">
```

**Update:**

You can actually just add col-md-6 class to the li element without changing row wrappers as you are aiming for 1, 2 or 4 elements per row depending on viewport width.

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a shot and it went from my current 4 columns to 2 columns, but only the first column was filled with products. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the ul outside foreach and this caused every element to have a row wrapper. I've edited my answer and it should be fine now.